# targeting specific html pages with window.location

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to JQuery and I've found myself stuck in a rut. Basically what im trying to do is send the user to a different html page depending on which button they choose with the .navmenu li's . I've got it to work fine for one location (index.html) but i'm not sure how to go about setting it for multiple pages. IE if user clicks 'projects li' i want them to go to projects.html. The effect here is is that when a user clicks a li in my side navigation, the div slides off screen when removing class '.move-right', waits .5s, then redirects to new html page. Can someone advise?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.navmenu').bind('click' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.left , .overleft').removeClass('move-right')

    setTimeout(function(event) {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }, 500);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

});

Theres probably some other errors in my code too, if you could advise that would help me. Thank you

Comment: You should provide a working example, otherwise i doubt anyone will understand what do you want.

Comment: We will need to see the html structure before we can appropriately answer your question. Can you update your question to include the way your nav is structured?

Comment: also try removing ```event.stopPropagation();```  https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular links, like

```
<ul class="navmenu"><li><a href="projects.html">See projects</a></li></ul>
```

Then in your JS:

```
// listen to click events on links in navmenu
$('.navmenu').on('click' , 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // the href attribute of clicked link
    var url = this.href; 
    $('.left , .overleft').removeClass('move-right');

    setTimeout(function(event) {
        // redirect after 500ms
        window.location.href = url;
    }, 500);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This way the links are fully functional, so the user can middle click to open in new tab, or right click and do whatever is in the context menu for links.

Comment: Actually, I am findind that when I click on the same li two times, the jquery doesnt appear to work, any suggestion as to why this might be?